# Visual studio closes immediately and cant repair.

Tags: windows, visual-studio

My problem is that Visual studio closes immediately after I open it with no errors.

I already tried to uninstall and install again and the problem starts again.
I have tried running CCleaner on the registry.
If I repair it I get this error and I suspect it has something to do with my problem.

[image]

I cant find the distributables in add or remove progamms to remove them.
I have tried downloading the binaries and running vc_redist.x86/x64.exe /uninstall.

and still get the repair error.

[image]

This happens for both visual studo 2015 and 2017.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was Oracle developer tools. After completely removing VS and reinstalling it started working.